# JPA: How to search by property expressions in `oneToMany` and `manyToMany` relations?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch the parent object data based on child search criteria.

The User Entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    protected String usertId;
    protected Collection<Contact> contacts;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
    public Collection<Contact> getContacts()
    {
        return contacts;
    }

    //getters & setters

}
```

And its child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact
{
    protected String phoneNumber;
    protected String zipCode;


    //getters & setters

}
```

And the `UserRepository` class is:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByZipCode(String zipCode);

}
```

I am trying to get all the user based on e.g. zip code but this giving below compilation error.

Invalid derived query! No property zipCode found for type User!

Can some help me with this or any sample tutorial on how to fetch records using  child fields

Comment: What is the `User` Entity and what is its relation to Contact and Account?

Comment: Sorry for confusion there is User and contact object which has one to many relation and I am trying to fetch the parent and child details based on child field passed from UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for `zipCode` in `User` Entity. while it's related to `Contact` Entity. just use the following method:

```
User findByContactsZipCode(String zipCode);
```

It means `User.contacts.zipCode`.

however this is a typical way, in some cases using this method makes miss understanding (suppose your `User` entity have a `contactsZipCode` property as well). to prevent this kind of problems, you can use `_` to separate `contacts` from `zipCode`.

```
User findByContacts_ZipCode(String zipCode);
```

for more details and examples you can read property expressions of JPA from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

I hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Hamid. Its not giving any compilation error now will check and test it once.